# querySelectorAll functions onclick with certain names

Tags: javascript

Can I get somehow all onclick function elements what starts with `onclick="tabbed('tabpage...` ?

I tried like:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[onclick^=tabbed('tabpage*')]");
```

However it´s not working.
Any Ideas?

Comment: This does not look right at all. What is your end goal and what are trying to do ? Please add all the relevant HTML and JS code - thanks

Comment: why don't you give the same class name, so that can select them easily

Answer (score 2):

You can use class name which is a good approach. But if you need the way you expected try like below,

```
document.querySelectorAll("[onclick=\"tabbed('tabpage*')\"]")
```

Answer (score 2):

The part of the query selector which checks if the string starts with particular letters is the `^=`. The `*` in your selector doesn't match any characters like you think it does, instead, you need to enter exactly what you want the `onclick` attribute to start with after your `^=`:

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll("[onclick^=\"tabbed('tabpage\"]");
console.log(elems.length, 'elements found');
```

```html
<button onclick="tabbed('tabpage')">A</button>
<button onclick="tabbed('tabpage', 'foobar')">B</button>
```

This does, however, match all elements which start literally with `tabbed('tabpage`, meaning it would match an incomplete onclick attribute like so:

```
<button onclick="tabbed('tabpage">A</button>
```

If that is an issue, you could consider selecting your onclick elements first and then filtering them based on a regular expression. This will prevent incomplete `tabbed` methods from being selected, and will only select tags with an `onclick` set to a tabbed function call (with no additional calls).

```js
const elems = [...document.querySelectorAll("[onclick]")].filter((e) => /^tabbed\('tabpage',?[^\)]*\)$/.test(e.getAttribute('onclick')));

console.log(elems.length);
```

```html
<button onclick="tabbed('tabpage')">A</button>
<button onclick="tabbed('tabpage', 'foobar')">B</button>
<button onclick="tabbed('tabpage">C</button> <!-- Not selected -->
<button onclick="tabbed('tabpage'); xyz('abc')">D</button> <!-- Not selected -->
```